# sql query update field based on value in 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

using mysql 5.5.36

im trying to update the value for field1 in table1 based on 2 conditions - table1 field2 = valuex, table2 field3 = value-y.

i know i can update a field value based on a field value in the same table with this...

```
UPDATE table
SET field1 = new-value
WHERE field2 = value-x;
```

can i update based on 2 different values in 2 different tables using this?

```
UPDATE table1
SET field1 = new-value
WHERE field2 = value-x;
FROM table2
WHERE field3 = value-y;
```

---

maybe i need to be more literal. These are the actual table names, field names and conditions. i haven't tried to update data across 2 linked tables before...so this is a good exercise for me.

im updating the table `qkt6v_propmid`, field catid to value = 12.

the conditions are:

qkt6v_iproperty stype value = 1

qkt6v_propmid propid value = qkt6v_iproperty id value (this is the common ID between tables). in the data below it is ID 3044.

qkt6v_propmid catid = 2

here is how the actual tables / fields breakdown...

```
TABLE qkt6v_iproperty
id      stype
3044    1
3045    4
```

TABLE qkt6v_propmid

```
id      prop_id     cat_id
7968    3044        0
7969    3044        2
```

Comment: yes you can update from 2 table and 2 different values.. but you must have key to connect table1 and table2

Comment: i understand what your saying. the 2 tables ARE linked together via an ID#. so i need to somehow add this condition: table2 field4 value = table1 field5 value. this is the ID# that matches the 2 tables together. how do i add that?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
UPDATE table1,table2 SET table1.field1 = new-value WHERE table1.field2 = value-x AND table2.field3 = value-y and table1.ID = table2.ID
```

this will update table1 who have field **field1** and link table1 and table2 via **table1.ID** and **table2.ID**

Comment: Please explain how some of this code works.  This will discourage copying and pasting without understanding.

Comment: i edited / added a more thorough explanation with samples of the 2 tables and their respective fields. thanks for everyones help btw.

Comment: would any sql pro's care to check this for me?...does the syntax look correct? will this work. its updating 1 value in 1 table with 1 condition in that 1st table and 2 conditions in a different table where 1 condition is that the primary key for the 1st table matches an id in the 2nd table. i started to rearrange and it made more sense. maybe this works?UPDATE qkt6v_propmid
SET cat_id = 12
WHERE cat_id = 2
FROM qkt6v_iproperty
WHERE stype = 1;
AND prop_id = id;

Comment: i need the condition that matches the primary key in table1 against a table2 id. it seems like some queries use a join and some use a sub query. is that right?

Comment: this is where i am now. i still get syntax error. im having issues. UPDATE qkt6v_iproperty_propmid
SET cat_id = 12
WHERE cat_id = 2;
FROM qkt6v_iproperty_propmid
JOIN qkt6v_iproperty ON id = prop_id
FROM qkt6v_iproperty
WHERE stype = 1;

Comment: now i have this...UPDATE qkt6v_iproperty_propmid
SET cat_id = 12
WHERE cat_id = 2;
FROM qkt6v_iproperty_propmid a
JOIN qkt6v_iproperty b ON a.id = b.prop_id
FROM qkt6v_iproperty
WHERE stype = 1; ## the 'a' and 'b' are what are tripping me up now. are these just arbitrary alias' set for the tables? im still getting a syntax error. someone throw me a bone?

Comment: UPDATE qkt6v_iproperty_propmid
SET qkt6v_iproperty_propmid.cat_id = 12
WHERE qkt6v_iproperty_propmid.cat_id = 2;
FROM qkt6v_iproperty_propmid
JOIN qkt6v_iproperty ON qkt6v_iproperty.id = qkt6v_iproperty_propmid.prop_id
FROM qkt6v_iproperty
WHERE qkt6v_iproperty.stype = 1; now im just floundering. is it possible / correct to specify fields this way? --> table.field obviously its more characters and that sucks but im curious. i see it written that way sometimes. this query also fails...syntax.